# List of amplitudes at 1-, 2-loops for scalar field theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams

I would like to know if there is any database/reference which has an explicit list of all the amplitudes that are known, at least in the more common scalar field theories like the $\phi^4$ and $\phi^3$ theories, to 1-, 2- or even higher loops. I am currently studying renormalization and would like to check if the calculations that I have done are indeed matching with the results. Please note that I am not necessarily looking for the derivations themselves.

Comment: Check out Loopedia

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/718417/2451 and links therein.