# Sources to find Feynman diagrams of scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams

I am currently doing a project i.e. collection of Tree level and 1-loop Feynman diagrams corresponding to various scalar fields and very soon I got out of sources. I am very much new to QFT. Can any one suggest me any books or references from which I can get Feynman diagrams of scalar fields other the $\phi^3$ and $\phi^4$ theory.

Comment: It will depend on your Lagrangian what diagrams you can write down, usually one formulates a Lagrangian and then from there derives the Feynman rules which are used to construct diagrams.

Comment: In general, I want the diagrams along with the equivalent expressions corresponding to any standard scalar field which  have already been well derived.

Comment: Well the best thing you can do is probably find the Feynman rules for the theory you want then construct all the diagrams you can from it. This is usually what would be done. Which theories did you need to look at specifically?

Comment: Like $\frac{\lambda}{4!}(\phi^*\phi)^2$

Comment: Which sources have you tried? Most intro QFT books should have this, for instance Peskin and Schroeder, Schwartz, etc

Comment: Many that includes Mark Srednicki, Matthew schwartz, Zee,Peskin and even Peskin and Schroeder and so but,still I didn't found it.